# How do I execute commands with quotation marks in bash?

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, sh, wget

Basically, I have a file (say.sh) which uses an api to save and play text to speech mp3 files. The api uses the URL: http://api.voicerss.org/?key=keygoeshere&src=TEXT_GOES_HERE&hl=en-gb&c=mp3&r=1&f=32khz_8bit_stereo

The script (bellow) uses wget to get the file. In theory, this code should work, but it doesn't. If I echo the wget command, it returns a working command, that successfully runs, but as soon as I remove the echo, it gets confused by the quotation marks and stops working.

```
#!/bin/bash
TA="http://api.voicerss.org/?key=MY_KEY_IS_HERE&src="
TB="&hl=en-gb&c=mp3&r=1&f=32khz_8bit_stereo"
wget -O example.mp3 \"$TA$@$TB\"
omxplayer example.mp3
```

If anybody here knows how to fix this, it would be very helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: To run the command I have tried `sh say.sh Text here` and `sh say.sh "Text here"`. Neither of which work -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know that you need to escape any quotes for the wget command, but i think if variables are appended next to each other, you can try using `{}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
TA="http://api.voicerss.org/?key=MY_KEY_IS_HERE&src="
TB="&hl=en-gb&c=mp3&r=1&f=32khz_8bit_stereo"
wget -O example.mp3 "${TA}${TB}"
omxplayer example.mp3
```

give that a try and let us know how it goes.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the post, the url in wget needs quotes because the url will have spaces in. I tried `"${TA}${@}${TB}"` and it returned the same results

Comment: Ah, managed to fix it using this and \"! Thanks for the help!

Comment: if it matters, you can experiment with using HTML encoding for the "Text" field.  the HTML entity for a "space" is "%20."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses! I managed to fix this by adding the "${TA}${@}${TB}" and using \" to declare a special character to get:

```
#!/bin/bash
TA="http://api.voicerss.org/?key=keygoeshere&src=\""
TB="\"&hl=en-gb&c=mp3&r=1&f=32khz_8bit_stereo"
wget -O example.mp3 "${TA}${@}${TB}"
omxplayer example.mp3
```